# handlebars.js and hide if list

Tags: css, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

Trying to learn this handlebars.js and currently I have:

```
<ul class="productView-thumbnails"{{#gt product.images.length 5}} data-slick='{
                "infinite": false,
                "mobileFirst": true,
                "slidesToShow": 5,
                "slidesToScroll": 1
            }'{{/gt}}>
            {{#each product.images}}
                <li class="productView-thumbnail">
                    <a
                        class="productView-thumbnail-link"
                        href="{{getImage this 'product_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}"
                        data-image-gallery-item
                        data-image-gallery-new-image-url="{{getImage this 'product_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}"
                        data-image-gallery-zoom-image-url="{{getImage this 'zoom_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}">
                        <img class="lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage this 'productview_thumb_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{this.alt}}" title="{{this.alt}}">
                    </a>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
```

so I need something to the effect of an IF statement that states if there’s only 1 image (li), then apply a display:none to the class productView-thumbnails

I am trying to hide the entire UL if there's only one LI returned., is this even possible?

Comment: If you hide an element by means of CSS, all content will be hidden as well – is this really what you want to achieve? Or would avoiding the UL and LI be suitable? That would keep your DOM correct.

Comment: thats the idea, the UL is a place for thumbnails below a main product image, I don't want to show the thumbnails if there's only one.

Comment: And did you already define that gt-helper, or is that pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to structure your handlebar blocks. The handlebar controls are not HTML elements, hence you can wrap partial HTML structure in if-statements.

Considering you have a gt-helper registered:

```
{{#gt product.images.length 1}}
<ul class="productView-thumbnails"{{#gt product.images.length 5}} data-slick='{
…}'{{/gt}}>
{{/gt}}
{{#each product.images}}
  {{#gt product.images.length 1}}
            <li class="productView-thumbnail">
  {{/gt}}
  …
  {{#gt product.images.length 1}}
  </li>
  {{/gt}}
{{/each}}
…
{{#gt product.images.length 1}}
</ul>
{{/gt}}
```

Comment: that code was already in the platform, I have no idea what GT even is... handlebars is totally new to me, but wrapping it in a new GT tag with that 1 completely works! Thank you. Clearly I need to learn more about this

Comment: Glad it helped. There is an npm package that provides 130 helpers, [{{gt}}](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helpers#gt) among them – maybe you have that installed?

Comment: not sure? I have BigCommerce and whatever it came with is what I have to work with. I had asked for a list of the 'helpers' but I wasn't able to get anything